# JavaScriptで「〜な大吉」といった１５種類程のおみくじを作成しているのですが「〜な」の箇所だけ小さいフォントで改行して表示させるにはどうすればいいのでしょうか。

Tags: javascript

JavaScriptで「〜な大吉」といった１５種類程のおみくじを作成しているのですが「〜な」の箇所だけ小さいフォントに変えて改行して表示させるにはどうすればいいのでしょうか。
又、画像も一緒に表示させたいです。

下記の形でコードを書いてあります。

```
{
  const btn = document.getElementById(`btn`);

  btn.addEventListener(`click` , () => {
    const results = ['〜なa','〜なb','〜なc',,,,,,];
    btn.textContent = results[Math.floor(Math.random() * results.length)];
  });
}
```

Comment: btnのHTML部分のコードも記述いただけると幸いです。仮にbtnがinputとかですと改行だったり装飾に制約があるので純粋にCSSを記述するだけはうまく行かない可能性があります

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`textContent`にはテキストだけをセットできて、修飾情報や画像は入れられません。HTMLを組み立てて、`innerHTML` でセットすればよいでしょう。

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const results = [{
    desc: '〜な',
    result: '凶',
    image: 'https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-cPqdLavQBXA/UZNyKhdm8RI/AAAAAAAASiM/NQy6g-muUK0/s400/syougatsu2_omijikuji2.png'
  }, {
    desc: '〜な',
    result: '小吉',
    image: 'https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-cPqdLavQBXA/UZNyKhdm8RI/AAAAAAAASiM/NQy6g-muUK0/s400/syougatsu2_omijikuji2.png'
  }, {
    desc: '〜な',
    result: '大吉',
    image: 'https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-cPqdLavQBXA/UZNyKhdm8RI/AAAAAAAASiM/NQy6g-muUK0/s400/syougatsu2_omijikuji2.png'
  }];
  const resultObj = results[Math.floor(Math.random() * results.length)];
  btn.innerHTML = `<div class="desc">${resultObj.desc}</div>
    <div>${resultObj.result}</div>
    <img class=i src="${resultObj.image}">`;
});
```

```css
.desc {
  font-size: smaller;
  color: darkGray;
}

.i {
  width: 24px;
}
```

```html
<button type=button id="btn">くりっく</button>
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！参考にさせていただきます！

Comment: @MakotoTanaka この回答で問題が解決した場合は、回答の承認を行ってくださいませ。https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers